# Color regions in a D3 map based on external data

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, d3.js

I am trying to make a map in D3 of the 12 provinces of the Netherlands and color them based on some mock data in an external JSON file:

```
[{"_id":"Groningen","value":52},
{"_id":"Friesland","value":18},
{"_id":"Drenthe","value":87},
{"_id":"Overijssel","value":93},
{"_id":"Flevoland","value":60},
{"_id":"Gelderland","value":7},
{"_id":"Utrecht","value":26},
{"_id":"Noord-Holland","value":52},
{"_id":"Zuid-Holland","value":72},
{"_id":"Zeeland","value":41},
{"_id":"Noord-Brabant","value":78},
{"_id":"Limburg","value":19}]
```

This is the code I have thus far. It successfully generates them map but right now colors each province as a function of the length of the province name (which is silly ofcourse):

```
var width = 960,
height = 500,
centered;

// Define color scale
var color = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain([1, 20])
   .clamp(true)
   .range(['steelblue', "yellow"]);

var projection = d3.geoMercator()
   .scale(5500)
   .center([6, 52.1])
   .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geoPath()
   .projection(projection);

// Set svg width & height
var svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

// Add background
svg.append('rect')
   .attr('class', 'background')
   .attr('width', width)
   .attr('height', height)

var g = svg.append('g');

var effectLayer = g.append('g')
   .classed('effect-layer', true);

var mapLayer = g.append('g')
   .classed('map-layer', true);

// Load map data
d3.json('data/provincesNL2.json', function(error, mapData) {
    var features = mapData.features;

    // Draw each province as a path
    mapLayer.selectAll('path')
      .data(features)
      .enter().append('path')
      .attr('d', path)
      .attr('vector-effect', 'non-scaling-stroke')
      .attr('fill', fillFn)
});

// Get province name
function nameFn(d){
   return d && d.properties ? d.properties.PROVINCIE : null;
}

// Get province name length
function nameLength(d){
   var n = nameFn(d);
   return n ? n.length : 0;
}

// Get province color
function fillFn(d){
   return color(nameLength(d));
};
```

I just do not know how to implement the values from the JSON file to represent the color of each province along the color scale. I am not to experienced with javascript and I thought this shouldnt be too hard but I just can not figure it out. Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this, one would be to use [d3.map](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#map). This allows you to look up values in the map with `map.get(key)`.

The general set up looks like:

`var lookup = d3.map(array, function(d) { return d.key; })`

Where `array` is your data array, and `key` is some property of each item in the data array that can be used as an identifier. To lookup a value, you can use:

`lookup.get(value)`

Where value is an identifying value/key - this will return the entire object that was in the data array. For your data this might look like:

```
var lookup = d3.map(data, function(d) { return d._id; });

lookup.get("Drenthe") // {"_id":"Drenthe","value":87}
```

To color the map you can get the identifying value/key from the element's datum. Here's a working example of d3.map used to color your data:

```js
var color = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,100])
  .range(["orange", "steelblue"])

var data = [{"_id":"Groningen","value":52},
{"_id":"Friesland","value":18},
{"_id":"Drenthe","value":87},
{"_id":"Overijssel","value":93},
{"_id":"Flevoland","value":60},
{"_id":"Gelderland","value":7},
{"_id":"Utrecht","value":26},
{"_id":"Noord-Holland","value":52},
{"_id":"Zuid-Holland","value":72},
{"_id":"Zeeland","value":41},
{"_id":"Noord-Brabant","value":78},
{"_id":"Limburg","value":19}];

var lookup = d3.map(data, function(d) { return d._id; });

// test a value:
console.log(lookup.get("Drenthe").value);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",400)
  .attr("height",100);
  
var squares = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("fill",function(d) { return color(lookup.get(d._id).value) })
  .attr("x", function(d,i) { return i * 20; })
  .attr("y", 40)
  .attr("width",16)
  .attr("height",16);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the domain for you colour scale using min and max value of your data object.

```
var colour = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([
    d3.min(dataObject, function(d) { return d.value }),
    d3.max(dataObject, function(d) { return d.value })
  ])
  .clamp(true)
  .range(['steelblue', "yellow"]);
```

In the callback function for `fill` attribute, you should find (you can do it various ways, depend on data structure) the value for current provinces and pass it to `colour` function.

```
.attr("fill", function(d, i) {
  var value = // here you should get for current data item ;

  return colour(value); // use this value for colour scale
})
```

Check [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqjmrcw3/) for Netherlands map (**I modified your data a bit, to simplify the example and hardcoded topojson object**).

Comment: But this does not color each province based on the value that is associated with the province from the JSON file, which is what I am trying to do :)

Comment: @MatthijsvanKesteren I rewrote my answer.